# Issue passing single quote as parameter from Jenkins to Ansible

Tags: jenkins, parameters, ansible, quotes, single-quotes

The string parameter in jenkins `dest_cmd` works fine and gets passed and read by ansible as below:

Jenkins pipeline script:

```
ansible-playbook -i /web/runcmd/allmwhosts.hosts /web/runcmd/copyfiles.yml -e dest_user=$dest_user -e '{ dest_cmd: $dest_cmd }' --tags validate"
```

The above works fine for all `dest_cmd` parameters however, it fails when the user enters single quotes `'` as you can see below:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ ansible-playbook -i /web/runcmd/allmwhosts.hosts /web/runcmd/copyfiles.yml -e dest_user=wluser -e '{ dest_cmd: arp `hostname` | cut -d' ' -f4 }' --tags validate
usage: ansible-playbook [-h] [--version] [-v] [-k]
                        [--private-key PRIVATE_KEY_FILE] [-u REMOTE_USER]
                        [-c CONNECTION] [-T TIMEOUT]
                        [--ssh-common-args SSH_COMMON_ARGS]
                        [--sftp-extra-args SFTP_EXTRA_ARGS]
                        [--scp-extra-args SCP_EXTRA_ARGS]
                        [--ssh-extra-args SSH_EXTRA_ARGS] [--force-handlers]
```

Can you please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of quotes within the single-quoted string:

```
'{ dest_cmd: arp `hostname` | cut -d' ' -f4 }'
                     problem quotes ^ ^
```

Try using double quotes:

```
'{ dest_cmd: arp `hostname` | cut -d" " -f4 }'
```

Comment: agreed but what if the user has to enter both single and or double quotes in the command? Any solution for such a scenario ?

Comment: Single quotes and double quotes work very differently in shell scripting. Generally I recommend using single quotes only when absolutely necessary to avoid ambiguity. A pretty good explanation of the differences is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: I m asking about a situation where the single user command contains both single as well as double quotes? What would be the solution in that case?

Comment: That's a different ask than the original question. I still recommend that it is best to rewrite your shell commands to avoid using both types of quotes.